# PDO rowCount Error

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO for the first time. I created this method, and I am getting this error:

```
 Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object
```

The following is my code.

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpassword)   

     function doesRecordExist($query) {
            global $db;
            try {
                $stmt = $db->query($query);
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();
                return $count;
            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                die($ex->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Can you help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use prepared statements: Plus you need to execute you query before you count it

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpassword)   

 function doesRecordExist($query) {
        global $db;
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            return $count;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a global variable. Pass this one as an object instead.

```
$db = new PDO(....);

 function doesRecordExist($query, PDO $db) {
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to create a table that the query was referring to. Sorry for any inconveniences